# Does lua optimize duplicate imports?

Tags: import, lua

In simple model I have 3 files:

```
base-module.lua
module-one.lua
module-two.lua
```

And this is my import connections:

```
module-two.lua < --|
     ^             |
     |             |
     |             |  
module-one.lua     |
     ^             |
     |             |
     |             |
base-module.lua ----
```

`module-one.lua` import `base-module.lua` and so on....
When I remove `base-module.lua` import from `module-two.lua` I see all functions and variables from `base-module.lua` but my imports is not inventive. Does lua optimize double import like it make pytho for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Lua does.

As manual on `require` in [section 5.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.3) says:

> Loads the given module. The function starts by looking into the
>   package.loaded table to determine whether modname is already loaded.
>   If it is, then require returns the value stored at
>   package.loaded[modname].

Comment: Great! This answer make me happy :)

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, yes.

[Long answer](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require):

> ### require (modname)
>
> Loads the given module. The function starts by looking into the
>   package.loaded table to determine whether modname is already loaded.
>   If it is, then require returns the value stored at
>   package.loaded[modname]. Otherwise, it tries to find a loader for the
>   module.
>
> To find a loader, require is guided by the package.loaders array. By
>   changing this array, we can change how require looks for a module. The
>   following explanation is based on the default configuration for
>   package.loaders.
>
> First require queries package.preload[modname]. If it has a value,
>   this value (which should be a function) is the loader. Otherwise
>   require searches for a Lua loader using the path stored in
>   package.path. If that also fails, it searches for a C loader using the
>   path stored in package.cpath. If that also fails, it tries an
>   all-in-one loader (see package.loaders).
>
> Once a loader is found, require calls the loader with a single
>   argument, modname. If the loader returns any value, require assigns
>   the returned value to package.loaded[modname]. If the loader returns
>   no value and has not assigned any value to package.loaded[modname],
>   then require assigns true to this entry. In any case, require returns
>   the final value of package.loaded[modname].
>
> If there is any error loading or running the module, or if it cannot
>   find any loader for the module, then require signals an error.